# How can I use DeleteMissing[] to delete "complicated rules" from a matrix

Tags: code-review

The following works as intended:

```
DeleteMissing[{{a, 1}, {b, 2}, {c, Missing[]}, {d, 4}, {e, 
   Missing[]}, {f, 5}}, 1, 1]
DeleteMissing[{a -> 1, b -> Missing[], c -> 3, d -> Missing[]}]
```

However, an analogous code below does not work.

```
DeleteMissing[{{a, 1} -> bir, {b, 2} -> iki, {c, Missing[]} -> 
   uc, {d, 4} -> dort, {e, Missing[]} -> bes, {f, 5} -> alti}, 1, 1]
```

which is supposed to give me:

```
{{a, 1} -> bir, {b, 2} -> iki, {d, 4} ->dort,  {f, 5} -> alti}
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `All` as the third argument in `DeleteMissing`:

```
DeleteMissing[{{a, 1} -> bir, {b, 2} -> iki, {c, Missing[]} -> uc, 
  {d, 4} -> dort, {e, Missing[]} -> bes, {f, 5} -> alti}, 1, All]
```

> {{a, 1} -> bir, {b, 2} -> iki, {d, 4} -> dort, {f, 5} -> alti}

```
DeleteMissing[{{a, 1} -> bir, {b, 2} -> iki, {{{{c, Missing[]}}}} -> uc, 
 {d, 4} -> dort, {e, foo[{{bar@{Missing[]}}}]} -> bes, {f, 5} ->  alti}, 1, All]
```

> {{a, 1} -> bir, {b, 2} -> iki, {d, 4} -> dort, {f, 5} -> alti}

Comment: I noticed that when I import data from Excel, texts such as `Missing[]` or `na` are imported as `String` and hence the above code does not work for strings (?), though it gives the right result for my question which does not have any string.

Comment: @TugrulTemel, you can replace `"Missing[]"` with `Missing[]` before you use `DeleteMissing`; i.e., `DeleteMissing[ Replace[importeddata, "Missing[]" -> Missing[], All], 1, All]`. Alternatively, you can use `Select[FreeQ["Missing[]" | _Missing]][importeddata]`